# Parse git - log file with python

Tags: python, regex, git, git-log

So i need to parse thing like this :

```
commit e397a6e988c05d6fd87ae904303ec0e17f4d79a2
Author: Name <email@email.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 9 21:29:10 2011 +0400

    commit message

 1 files changed, 21 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
```

and get Author name and number of insertions and deletions.

For the name i have this:

```
re.findall(r"Author: (.+) <",gitLog)
```

For the numbers i have this:

```
re.findall(r" (\d+) insertions\S+, (\d+) deletions",gitLog)
```

But i want to get a list of tuples of name,insertions and delitions with one regular-expression.

I tryed to do somthing like

```
re.findall(r"Author: (.+) <.+ (\d+) insertions\S+, (\d+) deletions",gitLog,re.DOTALL)
```

but it returns nothing...

So what is my mistake? How regular-expression should look like?

UPADTE:
wRAR is right, but somehow when i read i file and try to parse it i get the whole file as a name , and then last insertion and deletion, so it matches the whole file but not a single commit... [.+] gets the whole file but not a part of a commit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the repo and not some text dump of `git log`, save yourself the parsing trouble and generate different log output:

```
git log --pretty="%an" --numstat
```

Will produce output of the form:

> Author Name
>
> lines_inserted lines_deleted modified_file

Which you don't even need regex for. If you want to keep with regex, you need to match the `(+)` after insertions or else it will not match at all and not capture the numbers.

Comment: then you would have to run the log command each time for each type of information you need.

Answer (score 3):

You should use (directly or by borrowing the code) existing packages such as [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/git-python), but about your regex question, the provided regex for the provided text returns `[('Name', '21', '11')]` so I suppose it is right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that I used for parsing Git log with Python. Looks quite living:

https://github.com/gaborantal/git-log-parser

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question is :

```
re.findall(r"Author: (\S+) <.+\n.+\n\n.+\n\n.+ (\d+) insertions\S+, (\d+) deletions",gitLog)
```

But thanks for you answers anyway.